# How to write to HKLM without WOW redirection in WOW scenario?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I have a WOW scenario and want to change the value of Key at

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ABCD\

I am using this code :

```
String key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ABCD\";
RegistryKey reg64key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
RegistryKey reg_64bit_Name = reg64key.OpenSubKey(key);
reg_64bit_Name.SetValue("Name","ahsan");
```

However this is not working.  Can anyone kindly suggest what I need to do here ?

NB:
1. Not working means I am getting the following exception while running the app :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: _However this is not working._ Oh really? Has the flangebracket broken? Perhaps the widget handler hasn't interface properly? Or is there some other error occurring?

Comment: Is that your actual code? If so, your problem could be that you're writing to the key called "Key" instead of using your `key` variable.

Comment: You mention in passing that this is a WOW scenario, so presumably Registry redirection is involved. You also mention that you want to avoid WOW redirection, then you pass `RegistryView.Registry64` to OpenBaseKey, and then some return value is null (you haven't actually specified which line of code gets the null reference exception.) What are you trying to do here? Why is this a `WOW` scenario? If you give some helpful detail, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @stuartd : I am trying to change some value. Essentially, I am writing some test code and need to change some value before I run the test. 32 and 64 bit native works fine. I need the WOW scenario to work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, by "this is not working" can you please describe any error messages, exceptions compiler errors?

That being said your code has

```
reg64key.SetValue("Key","ahsan");
```

Where you will see you are using the `"Key"` (as a string). Trying changing this to.

```
reg64key.SetValue(key,"ahsan");
```

So you are using your variable instead of the string `"Key"`

**EDIT: After OP changed**

After your edits I went back and tried this for myself. Please see the code below (this is tested)

```
RegistryKey reg64key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
String key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ABCD";

if (reg64key == null)
    throw new Exception("reg64key");

var basekey = reg64key.OpenSubKey(key);
if (basekey == null)
    basekey = reg64key.CreateSubKey(key);

basekey.SetValue("Name", "ahsan");
```

You will see from the code the first thing we do is grab the `reg64key` for `HKLM`. Next we check that the `reg64key` is not null (shouldnt be null but you never know). Next we use the `reg64key` to open the key `"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ABCD"`. If this is not found (`baseKey == null`) then we create the key.

Finally you can set the key as you wish.

Hope this help.s

Comment: I have described the error. Also the issue you mentioned, while thoughtful, is not the case here. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh i see you edited the question. I have edited the answer. Cheers.

Comment: I see this error :   Error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Cannot write to the registry key.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowUnauthorizedAccessException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.EnsureWriteable()
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value, RegistryValueKind valueKind)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value)

Comment: Check your application compilation. Chances are you are trying to open the 64-bit registry on a 32-bit application. Check that you are compiling on AnyCPU.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i had a similar issue elsewhere, fixed it. Your code had an issue of trying to change the value after getting a read only handle, I fixed your code as well. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Essentially, we need to do reg64key.OpenSubKey(key, true);since we want to have write access to the registry key. Going with your code, it will have read access only.